# Как в начале и в конце каждой строки вставить текст?

Tags: php

Текст:

```
Один, два, три
Четыре, пять, шесть
Семь, восемь, девять
```

Как из него сделать, к примеру

```
<div>Один, два, три</div>
<div>Четыре, пять, шесть</div>
<div>Семь, восемь, девять</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно самый производительный способ, потому что не задействовано ничего лишнего, кроме непосредственно операции замены текста:

```
$text="<div>".str_replace("\n", "</div><div>", $source)."</div>";
```

Comment: А если концы строк виндовые? Т.е. "\r\n" или, к примеру, этот текст, на самом деле HTML-код и строки разделены "<br />"? Что тогда делать?

Comment: у Windows разделитель строк `\r\n`. Если наличие `\r` принципиально, то возврат каретки можно просто удалить из строки.

Comment: И если сильно принципиально еще и замена тэгов, то так:  

    $arr= Array("\r\n", "\n", "<br>", "<br/>");
    $text="<div>".str_replace($arr, "</div><div>", $source)."</div>";

Answer (score 0):

```
print sprintf('<div>%s</div>', $you_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Разбить по строкам (разделитель - все возможные окончания строк) в массив, а потом:

```
echo "<div>".implode('</div><div>', $str_arr)."</div>";
```